# Fast visual Git client for mac with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: git, version-control, github, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a Git client with keyboard shortcuts that can make common operations such as committing, merging, rebasing and switching branches quickly with the help of the visual representation.

I've used [GitUp](https://gitup.co/) for a few years, although it seems to have got slower. Especially, the performance  of the basic operations (commit/create branch/switch branches) drops significantly with the repositories with rich commit history and/or many branches. This has been already addressed with many issues that have been raised so far:

- [GitUp hangs on almost every action with a repo #942](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp/issues/942)
- [Delete local branch hangs for about 2-3 seconds #651](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp/issues/651)
- [very slow map view for large repositories #415](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp/issues/415)

For me, the workflow speed as well as the flexibility with merging and rebasing are the two most important operations and I'm happy to invest time in learning different keyboard shortcuts.

Which git clients would you recommend?